# How to apply custom styling to facebook login button

Tags: android, facebook, user-interface

I need to style facebook login button in order to look similar to google button. However, I see no documentation on how to achieve this in Android.

Is there any fast configuration for this? I don't really want to make a drawable of it.

Answer (score 1):

design a `Button` or what do you want in `xml` and in `setOnClickListener` to this custom button put this statment :

```
facebookButton.performClick();
```